# telegraph , python ,telegram bot

Tags: telegraph

How to upload several photos to telegraph in python?

for example I have several photos and they should be uploaded to telegraph using python?

create_page(title, content=None, html_content=None, author_name=None, author_url=None, return_content=False)[source]¶

there is such method create page, is it possible to send link of photos to content paramert(create page)

I am very bad at programming and especially for asking the questions, first question in stack overflow, sorry!

Comment: Hello Aziz! Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read this guide about [how to ask better questions on here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.